# Using ofstream* wrapper class with overloaded << operator on endl

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, function-pointers, ofstream, endl

**C++**

This is an attempt to make a class that mimics the output behavior of using the `<<` operator of an `ofstream`, as far as being able to use `std::endl` and write `string`s is concerned. The class has a single data member, the `ofstream` pointer. The class has two overloaded `<<` operators, one that takes an `std::string` and another that takes a pointer to a function, whose argument is an `ostream` reference and returns an `ostream` reference. That is the signature of `std::endl`, according to [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ostream/endl/?kw=endl). Technically, the below program works with the given input. It is able to print to file, two lines of text separated by two `std::endl`s. However, I want my **non**-string parameter overloaded `<<` operator to accept `std::endl` only, not something that merely matches its signature. I tried various combinations of placing `std::endl`in the argument list, with and without `*` and with and without `&`, but I got compiler errors for every combination. C++11 answers are also welcome.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class TextOut
{
public:
    TextOut(std::ofstream* ofsPar) : ofs(ofsPar) {}
    TextOut& operator<<(std::string s)
    {
        *ofs << s;
        return *this;
    }
    TextOut& operator<<(std::ostream& (*endlPar) (std::ostream& os))
    {
        *ofs << std::endl;
        return *this;
    }
private:
    std::ofstream* ofs;
};

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Enter filename: ";
    std::string filename;
    std::cin >> filename;
    std::ofstream myofstream(filename.c_str());
    TextOut myTextOut(&myofstream);
    myTextOut << "Hello," << std::endl << std::endl << "spacious world.";
    return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

```
Hello,

spacious world.
```

Comment: The correct way to do this sort of thing is to make a derived class of `std::streambuf`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I look at my ostream header file I see this for [`endl`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/endl):

```
template<typename _CharT, typename _Traits> inline basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&
  endl(basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& __os)
  {
     return flush(__os.put(__os.widen('\n')));
  }
```

so it looks like you would need to inherit from `basic_ostream` to make this work. Not sure you really want to do that.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there is no way to enforce a parameter to be a specific value at compile time.
If compile-time enforcement is not a requirement, you could use a simple assert like this to enforce that the parameter is `std::endl`:

```
assert(static_cast<std::ostream& (*) (std::ostream& os)>(&std::endl) == endlPar);
```

Comment: You need a cast for that to work since it is an overloaded function: `assert(static_cast<std::ostream& (*)(std::ostream&)>(&std::endl) == endlPar);`

Comment: Thanks, I made the change.